# Risc-V Linux, DTS interrupt PIN for MPU6050 driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-tree, iio

I’m connecting the MPU6050 to my RISC-V milkv duo board after compiling in the built-in driver. I get the following in `dmesg`:

```
[    0.805674] inv-mpu6050-i2c 0-0068: mounting matrix not found: using identity...
[    0.813447] inv-mpu6050-i2c 0-0068: Could not find IRQ 0
[    0.819145] inv-mpu6050-i2c: probe of 0-0068 failed with error -22
```

```sh
# i2cdetect -ry 0
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- 56 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I’m connecting the Interrupt pin to GPIOA26 and using the following DTS:

```dts
&i2c0 {
       status = "okay";
       clock-frequency = <100000>;
       mpu6050@68 {
        compatible = "invensense,mpu6050";
        reg = <0x68>;
        interrupt-parent = <&gpio0>;
        interrupts = <26 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_RISING>;
    };
};
```

What is the correct values for interrupt-parent and interrupts?

EDIT: full boot log: https://pastebin.com/ErNQxwB1

Comment: "*I’m ... using the following dts: ...*" - That is not a "*dts*"; it's just one node out of context.  That fragment of your DT is inadequate. What is the label `gpio0`? What is the full definition of that `i2c0` node? Have you looked at the bindings document, i.e. **Documentation/devicetree/bindings/iio/imu/invensense,mpu6050.yaml**? BTW filtering the bootlog with grep removes the context of those messages, which IMO is a bad idea. Instead of the big picture, you have have us looking through a pin-hole, and just viewing patches of the vista.

Comment: Hi AGAIN! I've seen that yaml file.. That's how I got those values for my node.. The gpio node is defined here: https://github.com/milkv-duo/milkv-duo-u-boot/blob/de98739c53683962a39c4845ad5a18b1a22ffc02/arch/riscv/dts/cv180x_base_riscv.dtsi#L206

Comment: I think that example targets ARM. So, I've also tried using `&plic0` as `interrupt-parent` in which case I get `inv-mpu6050-i2c 0-0068: trigger probe fail -22` instead..

Comment: "*I've also tried using `&plic0` ...*" - But you don't have a direct connection to the interrupt controller. Instead you wrote that you're using a gpio pin. So why isn't the interrupt-parent referring to a gpio-controller node such as `&porta`?

Comment: when I use `porta` the board wouldnt even boot. I'll get the boot log in a second..

Comment: here's the bootlog with `porta`: https://pastebin.com/tAKrkxHf looks like a kernel panic

Comment: "*The gpio node is defined here ...*" - Why are you pointing us to a U-Boot source when this is a Linux kernel issue? "*looks like a kernel panic*" - But perhaps there's more progress, and probe was almost completed? I'd insert a bunch of printk() or dev_info() statements to track progress through **inv_mpu_probe()** and **inv_mpu_core_probe()**. That call-trace doesn't make sense to me: how did **rdinit_setup()** get called from **inv_mpu_probe()**?

Comment: For this particular board there's no separate dts in the kernel.. this is the only location, and I believe it's passed on to the kernel..

Comment: I didn't understand the rest of your comment.. I'm not familiar with kernel programming at all.. I'm simply trying to use the driver and get a hardware node. But if it would help, I could do more debugging it you explain. But I think the issue is probably I'm denoting the wrong reference in the DTS node??

Comment: Interestingly if I remove `IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_RISING` bit, the kernel panic goes away. But now I again get `inv-mpu6050-i2c 0-0068: Could not find IRQ 0`

Comment: I begining to think this is a PINMUX problem.. the Interrupt pin I'm using is probably not configured as gpio..

Comment: This pin is muxed with ADC. Have you tried (at least for a test purpose) use GP22?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. On the datasheet the GP22 is mentioned as `PWR_GP04`. I don't know how to refer to this pin in the DTS? Anyway I have switched to another ARM board and see it working..

Comment: _... **another** ARM board..._?! Risc-V is completely different CPU architecture. Are you sure you understand the difference?

Comment: (Note, if you want to notify users about your new comments, add `@USER` to them. It is by luck I have checked this question again.)

Comment: Are you using custom Linux kernel sources for this board? The mainline Linux kernel 5.10 is too old. None of the mainline Linux kernels up to 6.7 include GPIO in the Linus DTS for this board, and it won't appear until the mainline Linux kernel 6.8-rc series - see mainline Linux kernel git [commit dd791b45c866](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=dd791b45c866b735601605b8dbceed4ab147db38).

Comment: yes it's a custom kernel, from the vendors repo..

Comment: @0andriy I meant to say I've abandoned using the board and moved on to an ARM based one.. since I"m new to embedded Linux, the complexities on the RISCV board was extra hurdles..